# Error parsing JSON for network server name

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-core, .net-core, appsettings

I'm trying to pull a value out of my appsettings.json file in a .Net CORE console app. The issue is that I'm trying to get to a network server to look for some files to process. I found examples of using a local file directory but when I try to do it with a network path I'm getting an error that it can not process the JSON.

Here is the local path example I found.

```
"path":"D:\\my\\path\\to\\file.txt"
```

This is an example of how I converted that to try to connect to a network server location but this fails.
`"ExportLocation": "\"\\\Eservername.domain.com\\filefolder\\subfolder\\\"`"

Comment: What is the exact error you're getting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's hard to know exactly what your problem is without seeing the exact error message, but this sequence of characters at the beginning of your string looks wrong:

> `\"\\\E`

Since `\` is used to escape the following character, then `\"` will be interpreted as `"` and `\\` will be interpreted as `\`. This leaves `\E` which is not a valid escape sequence. I also don't think you need `\"` at the beginning or end of your string, unless the code that uses this value expects the string to be "wrapped" with double quotes.

Try the following, and see if that resolves your parsing error:

> `"ExportLocation": "\\\\Eservername.domain.com\\filefolder\\subfolder\\"`

More information on other valid escape sequences can be found [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/json_simple/json_simple_escape_characters.htm).

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your JSON encoding simply has syntax errors.

The JSON encodings for the paths

```
C:\path\foo
\\server.domain\foo
```

are

```
"C:\\path\\foo"
"\\\\server.domain\\foo"
```

– that is, you need to just double the backslashes.